# Python character count is inaccurate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I'm working on opening a text file, display the total amount of characters in that file, and then categorize each character (alpha, numeric, punctuation, etc). My range is the ASCII table from 32-127 and for some reason, the character count seems to be over than what I saw when I put it into a character count online.

```
def totalLength():
    inFile = open("draft_UTF-8.txt", 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
    readFile = inFile.read()
    print("Total amount of characters with spaces included:", len(readFile))
    inFile.close()
```

In addition to this, whenever I categorize my file, my program displays that there are characters out of the ASCII range even though I didn't put any characters outside of the ASCII range.
Here is my code for organizing.

```
inFile = open("draft_UTF-8.txt", 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
readFile = inFile.read()
alpha = 0
num = 0
space = 0
special = 0
other = 0
for lines in readFile:
    for ch in lines:
        if ch in string.ascii_letters:
            alpha += 1
        elif ch in string.digits:
            num += 1
        elif ch == ' ':
            space += 1
        elif ch in string.punctuation:
            special += 1
        else:
            other += 1
```

I would then print each category. In my text file I have the following:

```
1234567890
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
~`!@#$%^&*()_-++|\}]{[“’:;?/>.<,
```

The output would be:

```
Total amount of characters with spaces included: 101

There are 52 occurrences of alphabetical characters.

There are 10 occurrences of numerical characters.

There are 0 occurrences of white spaces.

There are 30 occurrences of punctuation characters.

there are 9 occurrences of other characters.
```

I figured out that the other character occurrences are coming from the punctuations, but not sure which one. Any suggestions?

**EDIT: I figured out that the reason why I'm getting extra characters in my output is because of the encoding: ISO-8859-1. My main problem is that Python won't run my program unless I have this encoding in, mainly because I'm using a MAC OS.. It works without it on PyCharm, but on Python, my program would crash.**

Comment: Lines will end with newline characters. Have you considered it? Also, to iterate over lines you should use `readlines()` method.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're seeing.

Comment: My total character count is off by a few, and when the text file is larger, the total character count is off by hundreds. Also, in my text file, there are no 'other' characters, but my program output says there are.

Comment: Line feed characters?

Comment: Try using the [string.whitespace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace) category instead of `elif ch == ' ':`

Comment: I figured out what was giving me the extra character spaces. It's the encoding = "ISO-8859-1". For some reason, that boosts up my total character count and gives me some really weird numbers too. HOWEVER, I can't seem to open it on Python without the encoding, but works just fine with PyCharm...

Comment: Well, what encoding is your text file in? If you open e.g. an `ut-f8` encoded file with encoding=`iso-8859-1` you might end of with extra characters, namely the surrogates.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks dhke. Prior to adding the encoding = ISO-8859-1, I had various text files, one of which was being UTF-8 and a .txt file. originally, my file did not work on a regular .txt, but worked with UTF-8. Then, on Python, the UTF-8 didn't work, but worked on PyCharm. So now I had the encoding PLUS a UTF-8, which was the reason why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, got it. Thanks dhke. Prior to adding the encoding = ISO-8859-1, I had various text files, one of which was being UTF-8 and a .txt file. originally, my file did not work on a regular .txt, but worked with UTF-8. Then, on Python, the UTF-8 didn't work, but worked on PyCharm. So now I had the encoding PLUS a UTF-8, which was the reason why. Thank you! I apologize for the silly question, I'm new to coding so there was now way I would've figured this out.